# Can I use JOOQ as an SQL parser?

Tags: java, jooq

I'm trying to parse a SELECT statement in Java. I'm familiar with JOOQ, and was hoping to use that. I know it's not explicitly designed as an SQL parser—it's actually a lot more than that, so I was thinking there might be a way to use its internal parsers to parse SELECT queries.

I saw some information on how to access some of JOOQ's internals using the Visitor pattern, but I need to navigate inside the query using a tree-like structure that will allow access to each part of the query individually. I don't want to use the Visitor pattern for all use cases.

Is this possible? How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. [jOOQ has a parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/) that can be used:

- [Programmatically](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-api/)
- [As a CLI](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-cli/)
- [Online, as a SQL dialect translator](https://www.jooq.org/translate/)

As of jOOQ 3.17, there's [an experimental model API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/) which can be used to traverse your expression tree externally, e.g. using pattern matching, or [internally](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/model-api-traversal/) using the new [`Traverser`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Traverser.html) API. It is also still possible to traverse the expression tree using a [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) when rendering the expression tree back to SQL.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Eder. Would you say it will be easy enough to use the internals of JOOQ to achieve this goal (without the public API)? Would you recommend to do that? If so, would love to hear from you where do you recommend to start the learning curve.

Comment: *"Would you say it will be easy enough to use the internals of JOOQ to achieve this goal (without the public API)"* - For a quick and dirty job using reflection, yes absolutely, this is doable. At the risk of breaking even when doing patch release upgrades, but this could still be manageable if you write some unit tests that validate your internal assumptions. *"Would you recommend to do that?"* - Of course not :) *"If so, would love to hear from you where do you recommend to start the learning curve."* - I don't want to "document" this hackery, so I'm afraid you're on your own...

Comment: Will re-evaluate in the future again if / when JOOQ will support such capabilities officially. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dblike: Yep. This is definitely something we want to support officially, eventually.

Answer (score 1):

> [A full-fledged SQL parser is available from `DSLContext.parser()` and from `DSLContext.parsingConnection()` (see the manual's section about parsing connections for the latter).](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/)

The [SQL Parsing API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-api/) page gives this trivial example:

```
ResultQuery<?> query = 
DSL.using(configuration)
   .parser()
   .parseResultQuery("SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b')) t(a, b)");
```

`parseResultQuery` is the method you need for a single SELECT query, use [`parse(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.11.x/org/jooq/Parser.html#parse(java.lang-String)) if you may have multiple queries.

Comment: Thanks, but there doesn't seem a way I can see in the docs that allows to navigate through the structure of the query in a tree-like structure..
Can you suggest how can I inspect the different parts of the query once it was parsed with this method?

Comment: Hm, it seems harder than I thought (and undocumented and unsupported, so it can break on jOOQ update and _will_ break if/when it switches to Jigsaw modules). But the only way I can see is to put your classes into `org.jooq.impl` package, then you can cast the `Query` to `SelectQueryImpl` and use its `get...` methods to get at the parts of the query :( Since jOOQ's author is active on Stack Overflow, hopefully he'll be here to give a better option if there is one.